# Why doesn't this bash expr command work?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, fedora

I am trying to increment a variable in a bash script and it is not working. Here is my code:

```
#! /bin/bash

COUNTER=0
while [ $COUNTER -lt 5 ]
do
    echo "i will add this line to file mycreation">>./myfile
    COUNTER = `expr $COUNTER + 1`
done
```

The quotes around the `COUNTER` assignment are backticks.

I tried replacing `COUNTER` with `$COUNTER` like this:

```
$COUNTER = `expr $COUNTER + 1`
```

But that did not solve the problem and gave me the following error:

```
line7: 0: command not found.
```

Comment: The command 0 not found error appears when you use `$COUNTER` on the LHS of the assignment - `$COUNTER` expands to 0 and the shell then tries to execute that command.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

As [@Cory](https://stackoverflow.com/users/446554/cory-klein) rightly pointed out, there should not be spaces around the equal sign or else bash will confuse `COUNTER` for a command.

```
COUNTER=$(expr $COUNTER + 1)
```

#### going off-topic ...

That said, you could avoid having bash fork a subprocess by using the following alternatives:

- Using the [bash builtin 'let' command](http://ss64.com/bash/let.html):

  ```
  let COUNTER="COUNTER + 1"
  ```
- or, using bash c-style expression:

  ```
  (( COUNTER++ ))
  ```

In fact, your while loop can be written as:

```
for ((COUNTER=0; COUNTER <= 5 ; COUNTER++))
do
    echo "i will add this line to file mycreation">>./myfile
done
```

#### Breaking down the error message

When you were met with the error:

```
line 7:   0:    command not found.
'-----'  '--'  '------------------'
   |       |                 |
location   |            Description of error.
          culprit
```

my guess is what you had on line 7 was

```
$COUNTER = `expr $COUNTER + 1`
--------   --------------------
    |                 |
Evaluated to 0        |
                  Evaluated to 1
```

What bash ends up see is `0 = 1` and since bash statements are generally in the form `command arg1 arg1 ...`, bash interprets it as run the command `0` with arguments `= 1`. Thus the error message : `0: command not found`.

When you removed the spaces around the equal sign, what bash ends up interpreting is:

```
0=1
```

which means run command `0=1` with no arguments, hence the error `0=1: command not found`.

Variable assignments should be in the form `VAR_NAME=VALUE` (without the `$`), so the syntax you should be using is:

```
COUNTER=`expr $COUNTER + 1` # or any of the variants above
```

which bash evaluates and eventually interpret as:

```
COUNTER=2
```

Comment: Just be sure to shebang with `/bin/bash` if using bashisms, I think some of them actually turn off if bash is invoked as `/bin/sh` (POSIX) or if /bin/sh doesn't point to bash at all (dash on some systems).

Comment: Hello I removed the spaces around it however all it did is it's now giving me line:7 0=1 command not found. why did it change from 0:0 to 0:1 baffles me. Maybe i shouldn't be using expr at all? I don't understand why it's listed as useful command. Thanks

Comment: @Marin when you encountered the error, did you have a $ sign at the beginning? It should be COUNTER=.. not $COUNTER=...

Comment: answer updated, assuming my hunch is correct.

Comment: thanks Shawn! It worked, for some reason the spaces did the trick but I still don't get it why it's so sensitive? Thanks I guess I should just stick to AWK

Comment: +++++1 Thanks for explaining "let", "(( COUNT++ ))" and "for (( ))" =)

Answer (score 6):

Remove the spaces around the equals sign:

```
COUNTER=`expr $COUNTER + 1`
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way.

```
COUNTER=$(($COUNTER + 1))
```

Comment: not well documented, but you don't have to dereference the variables inside the arithmetic expression: `COUNTER=$((COUNTER+1))` or `((COUNTER++))` as has been mentioned

Answer (score 2):

```
for i in {0..4}; do 
    echo "i will add this line to file mycreation" >> ./myfile
done
```